# How to rescale smoke domain without having smoke rescale

Tags: transforms, smoke-simulation

I'm fairly new to Blender, and I was trying to do an animation involving a smoke trail. The method I'm using is a UV Sphere follow a Bezier Curve, and then adding the quick smoke to the UV Sphere. I've seen tutorials on Youtube where they rescale the smoke domain, and the smoke emitted remains untouched. However, when I try to rescale my domain to fit the Bezier Curve, the smoke also scales out. Similarly, when I move the domain, so too does the smoke. This confuses me because the in the tutorials this does not happen. Are there any settings I am not aware of or something I'm not understanding?

Comment: can u link such a tutorial? sounds weird so...;)

Comment: @Chris this is the one I was using, the part I'm talking about is at 2min40s:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMh0pyMt1YE